# Google Analytics Event Tracking on Button

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I'm attemptng to use Google Analytics event tracking on a landing page.  I've got the code in two places on the page, attached to two elements, tracking the clicks on those elements.

In one spot - a pop-out lightbox video - the tracking works perfectly.  It picks up in GA instantly.

However, with the other spot on the page (the more important one), I can't seem to get it to pickup in GA.  The code is implemented in the exact same way, and using the Google Analytics debuggers in Chrome, both seem to be firing off the exact same information on click.

In one instance, the code is in  and in the other in the  element.

I've attached the two snippets of code below.

Any help at all would be really appreciated.

**WORKING CODE:**

```html
<a class="button" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/134791294?autoplay=1" target="_blank" id="fancybox-video2" data-fancybox-type="iframe" class="fancybox.iframe" onclick="ga('send','event','played-video','clicked-play','button');">Watch the video</a>
```

**INCORRECT CODE:**

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="ga('send','event','Signed-Up','clicked-button','Free-Trial-14-Days');">Get Started</button>
```

Comment: Are you able to post (or PM me) the site with the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

What's most likely happening is the `<button>` example is submitting a form, which is telling the browser to navigate to a new page, so the existing page is being unloaded. And typically browsers will stop executing JavaScript once the page starts unloading, so your `ga('send', ...)` click handler never finishes.

The solution to this is to intercept the `submit` event, make the `ga('send', ...)` call, and then retrigger the submit in the send call's [`hitCallback`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hitCallback).

**Update:** when using `hitCallback` for essential functionality like a form submit, it's important to handle the case where the hit fails to send. You can do with this a `setTimeout` whose timeout gets cleared by a successful `hitCallback` invocation.

Answer (score 0):

As Philip mentioned you likely need to wait for the event to fire into Google Analytics (you should see it fail if you preserve the log in Chrome network tab). As an alternative to using the hitCallback (which could cause your link to not work if there is an error/delay on Google's end) is to use a setTimeout.

Simple jQuery example

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Note: be more specific!
    $("button").each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        var target = $(this).attr("target");

        $(this).click(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            ga('send','event','Signed-Up','clicked-button','Free-Trial-14-Days');
            setTimeout(function() { // Wait 300ms for tag to send to GA
                window.open(href,(!target?"_self":target)); 
            },300);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Using `setTimeout` is not a very reliable solution, though @williamvicary does make a good point that you'll need to handle the (albeit unlikely) case that the hit fails. Using a combination of `setTimeout` and `hitCallback` will accomplish this.